# How to take an average by dynamically changing the absolute reference for dynamic height of arrays?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

| A | B(Expected result) |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 |
| 20 | 15 |
| 30 | 20 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| 5 | 5 |
| 8 | 6.5 |
| 4 | 5.7 |
| 11 | 7 |
|  |  |
| 6 | 6 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4.3 |
| 15 | 7 |

Basically, I want to update the absolute reference `$B$1` dynamically with the array change. For example, `=average($B$1:B3)` dynamically. Like `=average($B$6:B9)` and `=average($B$11:B14)` and average only until the next blank cell found.

How can I do this?

Comment: If the blank rows are for grouping purposes, then consider adding a column with an grouping identifier, then you can either pivot the data, or use `averageifs`

Comment: AVERAGEIF function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the below formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(IF(B2<>"",IF(COUNTBLANK($B$1:B1)=0,1+COUNTBLANK($B$1:B1),1+COUNTBLANK($B$1:B1)),""),IF(B2<>"",AVERAGEIF($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2),""),""),"")
```